# JavaScript eval doesn't work when passing a href

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was not clear first time about **`ajax`** requests.

When I click on the link another one should appear.

Here it is what I'm trying to do (simplified),
but the problem is when it appears the JS inside it doesn't want to run.

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="javascript:suggest('result'); return true;">click to see the link</a>
</body></html>
```

JavaScript

```
function evalResponse (request)
{
    try
    {
        //var responseText = request.responseText.replace (/\n/g, " ");
        var responseText = request.responseText;
        return eval('(' + responseText + ')');
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert ("line: " + e.lineNumber + "\nmessage: " + e.message + "\nName: " + e.name);
    }
}


function suggest(target_div)
{
    
    var opt = {
        // Use POST
method: 'post',
        // Send this lovely data
postBody: 'Action=Edit&search_word=' + search_item + '&target=' + textarea,
        // Handle successful response
onSuccess: function(t) {
            
            var json = evalResponse (t);
            
            data = json[1];
            
            if (errors.errorText == undefined)
            {
                           document.getElementById('target_div').update(data['link']);
            }


        },
        // Handle 404
on404: function(t) {
            alert('Error 404: location "' + t.statusText + '" was not found.');
        },
        // Handle other errors
onFailure: function(t) {
            alert('Error ' + t.status + ' -- ' + t.statusText);
        }
    }

    new Ajax.Request('handler.php', opt);
}
```

PHP handler:

```
    $jsonArray = array();
    $jsonArray[1]["link"] = '<a href="javascript:alert(\'fdg\');" onClick="return true;">link</a>';

$json = new Services_JSON();
echo $json->encode($jsonArray);
```

Comment: There's nothing in what you posted about ajax or requests.

Comment: As you can see in [this fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/nuwLn/) everything works like expected: Both links are clickable and opens a alert box as defined in the HTML. If you want prevent the execution of the javascript link you need to return `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some small errors which may be caused by simplifying your code.

```
postBody: 'Action=Edit&search_word=' + search_item + '&target=' + textarea
```

In this line are two undefined variables `search_item` and `textarea`. In the fiddler I modified this line to get a result from fiddler which is equal to that what comes from your php script:

```
{"1":{"link":"<a href=\"javascript:alert('fdg');\" onClick=\"return true;\">link<\/a>"}}
```

However I would not recomment to use eval! It is dangerous better use `JSON.decode(response)` that parses the result from the server and prevents executing e.g. a alert from the server.

```
if (errors.errorText == undefined)
```

There are you also accessing nonexisting objects also your check is wrong. `errors` is in this case undefined so you need to check this too. A correct comperation looks like that with the `typeof` operator:

```
if (typeof(errors) === "undefined" || typeof(errors.errorText) === "undefined")
```

Finally you have another small error you added too much qoutes in this line:

```
document.getElementById('target_div').update(data['link']);
```

I guess that you wanted to use this line:

```
document.getElementById(target_div).update(data['link']);
```

All together your example will work. See also this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/nuwLn/3/) with all changes.

Comment: Hey, you have a some inaccuracies here. For example, [typeof](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) is an operator and not a function. You also don't need a `typeof` check on object properties [they return undefined](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) if not found rather than throwing a typerror. Also I'd suggest [=== over ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm a little confused about the undefined check it should be so correct right? In Firebug that runs like expected now.

Comment: `typeof errors === "undefined"` . When you do `typeof(errors) === "undefined"` it's like doing `-(5)` for negating a number. As for the second part, it's enough to check `errors.errorText === undefined` instead of typeof (see the algorithm in my previous comment)

Comment: This worked, thanks for the code explanation.

JSON.decode(response) - which library should i use for it?